# gopls disable struct auto-fill

Tags: go, gopls

I've written Golang code using Neovim+nvim-cmp. The language server **gopls** always auto-fills structs with initial values. For example:

```golang
a := &MyStruct{}
```

After saving the file, it modifies the struct to:

```golang
a := &MyStruct{
  Int1: 0,
  String2: "",
  //...
  PointerN: nil,
}
```

Seems it only does this if the cursor is currently inside the struct, but still, any way to disable this feature? Or trigger this feature manually by hotkey?

Answer (score 2):

There is an analyzer option `fillstruct`, described [here](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/analyzers.md), which causes the problem and is enabled by default. Problem solved after setting it to *false*:

```lua
lspconfig['gopls'].setup{
    cmd = {'gopls'},
    --...
    settings = {
        gopls = {
            analyses = {
                fillstruct = false,
            },
        },
    },
}
```

It seems that VSCode also enables this by default, described [here](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/settings.md#settings-for-gopls), but it doesn't fill it automatically. Instead, it shows a yellow bulb to let user click to do the filling.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see that behavior, using latest VSCode 1.66.1, Go 1.18 and [gopls 0.32.0](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/releases/tag/v0.32.0), with [gopls v0.8.2](https://github.com/golang/tools/releases/tag/gopls%2Fv0.8.2).

Check first if the issue persists when you remove all other plugins you might have with your VSCode.